# 3D Pythagoras program not returning correct results

Tags: python, math, algebra, pythagorean

So I want to calculate the distance from the two furthest points in a cuboid. The mathematical equation for this is z^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 but when I do that it doesn't return correctly.

```
from math import *

dimension = input("What dimension: ")

if dimension == ("3D") or dimension == ("3d") or dimension == ("3"):
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = (sqrt((a**2) + (b**2)))

    z = (sqrt((a**2) + (b**2) + (c))) 
    rounded_z = round(z, 4)

    print(rounded_z,'cm')
else:
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))

    c = (sqrt((a**2) + (b**2)))
    rounded_c = round(c, 2)

    print(rounded_c,'cm')
```

For example:

if a = 6

and b = 2

It should be 7 cm [Source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/pythagoras3drev1.shtml). But it returns 6.8062!! Why? please help.

Comment: why do you expect the square root of 40 (6*6 + 2*2) to be 7?  Clue: it isn't.

Comment: You have a simple equation with 3 variables. Why don't you just input all 3? Your "calculated" `c` is nowhere near the third value in the example.

Comment: **AF** is 7cm, not **AC**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood 3D cuboid. In 3D, you need to have three inputs, not 2 inputs. The corrected code is the following:

```
import math

dimension = input("What dimension: ")

if dimension == ("3D") or dimension == ("3d") or dimension == ("3"):
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))
    c = int(input("c = "))

    z = math.sqrt(a**2 + b**2 + c**2) 
    rounded_z = round(z, 4)

    print(rounded_z,'cm')
else:
    a = int(input("a = "))
    b = int(input("b = "))

    c = (math.sqrt((a**2) + (b**2)))
    rounded_c = round(c, 2)

    print(rounded_c,'cm')
```

Test it based on your Source:
a=2, b=3, c=6 produce 7 as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In the 2d case, you're calculating [image: c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}] which looks correct to me for a triangle.  But the answer isn't 7.  And it isn't a cuboid.

In the 3d case, you're calculating [image: z=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c}] which looks all kinds of wrong.

Why don't you explain what you want to calculate, and whether you want to look at the 2d case or the 3d case?  If you're interested in a cuboid, why are you asking for the number of dimensions?